# .net Repeater removes duplicate data

Tags: c#, ado.net, repeater, informix, duplicates

I have a repeater that I am trying to show data based on an sql statement. However for some reason if I have multiple rows of the same entry in the repeater, it only shows one. For example:

**In the database(informix)**:

- Payroll Deduction 250.00
- Payroll Deduction 250.00
- Payroll Deduction 250.00
- Payroll Deduction 250.00
- Student Health Insurance 1100.00

**Displayed in the repeater:**

- Payroll Deduction 250.00
- Student Health Insurance 1100.00

Any idea why this might be? The SQL I use in the code (below) works fine when I run it in the database.

```
private DataTable GetCreditData ( string id, string sessyr )
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection ( );
        conn.ConnectionString = cxConnStr;

        // Define our SQL
        String sql = "select  ABS(t1.amt) as amt , t2.txt from subtr_rec t1, subt_table t2 where t1.subs = 'S/A' and t1.tot_prd = ? and t1.subs_no=? and t1.amt < 0  and t1.tot_code = t2.tot_code and t1.subs = t2.subs UNION select t1.amt, t2.txt from aid_rec t1 join  aid_table t2 on t1.aid=t2.aid where t1.sess =? and t1.yr = ? and t1.id = ? and  ((stat='A' and amt_stat='AA') or (stat='I' or amt_stat='AA'))";

        // Command
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand ( );
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = sql;

        command.Parameters.Add ( new OdbcParameter ( "sess", sessyr ) );
        command.Parameters.Add ( new OdbcParameter ( "id", id ) );
        command.Parameters.Add ( new OdbcParameter ( "sess2", CurrSess ) );
        command.Parameters.Add ( new OdbcParameter ( "yr", CurrentYr ) );
        command.Parameters.Add ( new OdbcParameter ( "id2", id ) );

        // Create a DataTable to store our Cached results.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable ( );

        // Create a DataAdapter used to fill the DataTable
        OdbcDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter ( );

        // Associate the DataAdapter and select command created above
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

        try
        {
            // Open Database.
            conn.Open ( );

            // Fill DataTable.
            dataAdapter.Fill ( dt );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            edException.Error = ex;
            this.ParentPortlet.ShowFeedback ( FeedbackType.Message, "There was an error looking up term credits." );
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open )
            {
                // Release our resources (close db connection)
                conn.Close ( );
            }
        }
        return dt;

    }
```

Here is where the data table is bound to the repeater (page_load):

```
DataTable creditdata = GetCreditData ( Host, CurrSess + CurrentYr.Remove ( 0, 2 ) );
TermCredits.DataSource = creditdata;
TermCredits.DataBind ( );
```

Comment: Are you able to run the SQL against the DB to see what it is returning - that way we can isolate whether it is a SQL command problem or the repeater itself!

Comment: The issue was with the Union in the sql statement. The union should be "Union All" in order to prevent removing the duplicates.

Comment: @NLarkin you should probably delete this question

Answer (score 1):

@NLarkin - hope you don't mind me putting this in an answer after the fact so to speak.  I'm trying to build up a bit of a portfolio and would like to bolster my online presence so to speak.

So, recapping my comment - check the results the SQL produces.  As there is more than 'one moving part' here, this will allow you to isolate the problem.  If the SQL produces the output you expected, then you know it's the repeater and obviously, if it doesn't, you know it's the SQL. :)

In general - (and hoping I'm not teaching you to suck eggs) when you have these layer separations, it's always a good idea to check from the bottom up that each 'layer' is producing the results you expect.

Hope this was useful, and happy coding!!
Cheers,
Chris.